# Selecting a row from a table that matches pattern

Tags: bash, db2

I'm trying to select a specific row that matches a pattern through bash. But something is not working and I get empty output (0 record(s) selected.). Code looks like that:

```
su --login root -c "db2 connect to TILT; db2 \"select * from TABLE1 where COLUMN4 like '%\"selections\":[{\"college\":[\"9\",\"28\",\"29\",\"34\",\"35\",\"37\",\"48\",\"54\",\"55\",\"67\"]%'\""
```

The row from column4 that I'm trying to access looks like this:

```
,{"changelog":1},"selections":[{"college":["9","28","29","34","35","37","48","54","55","67"]
```

What am I missing?
Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: When I get problems like this, I simplify the like value.  Start with just "selections".  Then add more and more until it starts to break.  Probably a quoting issue.

Comment: I have a feeling that the quotes won't actually appear in the fields.  Try `select top 1 * from table1` and take a look at the data.  As Nic said, break it down into a smaller `like`.  For example `select top 10 * from TABLE1 where COLUMN4 like '%selection%'`.  I added the `top 10` in case this returns the entire table.

Comment: I've tried that `select * from TABLE1 where COLUMN4 like '%\"selections\"%'\""` and I got all of the rows, however when I add `:` there are no rows in the output. Escaping it like `\:` does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show me exactly what you used?

Comment: Exactly: `su --login root -c "db2 connect to TILT; db2 \"select * from TABLE1 where COLUMN4 like '%\"selections\"%'\""` And after adding `:` to it: `su --login root -c "db2 connect to TILT; db2 \"select * from TABLE1 where COLUMN4 like '%\"selections\":%'\""`

Comment: Honestly, that looks correct.  Any chance you could show one of the records from column4 that gets returned with the query that works?

Answer (score 1):

You escape the quotes for DB2 argument, but inside them, quotes should be escaped, too, to distinguish them from the end quotes for the db2 argument. Also escaping the already escaped quotes: `\\\"`

So instead e.g.

```
... '%\"selections\": ...
```

You should write

```
... '%\\\"selections\\\": ...
```

Comment: @Sergio I have had there three backslashes in my answer and it works on my bash. Why did you "multiply it" to five backslashes? It doesn't work, at least on my bash...

Comment: That was my mistake, I corrected it. Remember to put backticks around your in-line code to improve code format. When writing  code blocks indent your code with four spaces. Here are some guidelines for how to format code in stackoverflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks